# Are there active proposals for the next large space station (post-ISS) to use artificial gravity?

Tags: crewed-spaceflight, space-station, microgravity, health, commercial

The ISS has supported a crewed presence in space for twenty years now and while parts have been added over time, [key original components](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zvezda_(ISS_module)) are 20+ years old.

Crewed presence is usually limited to a half-year at a time, though there have been a few stays of about a year. Despite an aggressive exercise regiment and other countermeasures, [astronauts experience health problems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Space_Station#Crew_health_and_safety) like bone loss and vision issues due to extended exposure to microgravity.

I was wondering; are there any active proposals for a future crewed space station (probably commercial) to use artificial gravity?

Comment: This is an important question. I've adjusted the wording to avoid asking for opinion-based answers and to add some background in order to better fit the site's style. Feel free to roll back or edit further.

Comment: Do you mean proposals that are planning to be built, or just proposals in general?

Comment: It's certainly an important question. Our knowledge of how gravity affects living organisms is basically limited to 0 g, 1 g and (via centrifuges) higher gravity levels. We really don't know what happens in the range between 0 and 1, yet this is the range in which many planets and moons fall.

Comment: [Nautilus-X](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nautilus-X) was one proposal for a rotating wheel space station, but it didn't make it past the concept stage. The Space Islands Group also proposed [rotating wheel space stations](http://spaceislandgroup.com/wheel-stations.html), but it also didn't get past the concept stage and they were too large to be realistic in the near future. (Also the ISS [Centrifuge Accommodations Module](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centrifuge_Accommodations_Module) was proposed for specimens smaller than 0.62 m, but it was cancelled.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Note: Engineering Judgement Applied when figuring what `active proposal` means*

No, there are no active proposals for a future crewed space station to use artificial gravity.

The only planned space station which has a realistic chance of being built close to its announced schedule is the '[Chinese large modular space station](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_large_modular_space_station)'

It is a free-fall design.

You can peruse a list of planned space stations [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_space_stations). All are free-fall designs.

Comment: We as Humans get an F for no-effort...

Answer (score 2):

Roskosmos has plans to build a Mir-type orbital station (without artificial gravity) using new ISS modules.

[image]

Roskosmos after 50 years of work with orbital stations in Earth orbit plans to build a small lunar orbital station.

[image]

All interests of Roscosmos on the Moon:
[image]

Comment: No giant spinning wheel?

Comment: artificial Graviteeeee? (yes thats emphaseeeees)

Comment: Just to inject a dose of skepticism: Roscosmos isn't doing so hot and has a history of making big plans and promises but then never executing. I wouldn't be surprised if the agency's human spaceflight program does not survive past the planned shutdown of the ISS.

Comment: @Dragongeek The published plans are not a work plan. This is an attempt to get funding for several years in advance.The real picture can be seen in the economic courts in which Roscosmos participates.